# Oracle SQL: Create a new field based on multiplying 2 columns

Tags: oracle, query

I think I might be overlooking something obvious here. I'm not asking someone to write the whole code for me, I just need a hint or a link to a similar case, please. I'm posting it without a test case. Thanks in advance.

Here is my table:

```
Select Currency, Amount
from ABC_TABLE
```

Output:

[image]

So *Amount* is the amount by currency, we have these in EUR, USD and GBP. Here is my question:

I need to create a new column lets say *Amount_CNY* that represent each amount, but exchanged to "Yuan (CNY)".
So this "new" column resultant of the existing columns
The thing is each currency has a different exchange rate, as of today:
For EUR:

1 EUR: 7,74 Yuan

For USD:

1 USD : 7 Yuan

For GBP:

1 GBP: 8,23 Yuan

We keep this information *(7,74; 7; 8,23)* in the table,  FX_RATE is the field. I have tried to use "case when" but  How can I do this, I have tried to use "case" condition, but can't manage to change the amount for each curency.

This is my desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to create a new column lets say Amount_CNY that represent each
> amount, but exchanged to "Yuan (CNY)". So this "new" column resultant
> of the existing columns The thing is each currency has a different
> exchange rate

This can be done by using Generated Columns.

```
CREATE TABLE ABC_TABLE ( 
Currency VARCHAR2(10) ,
Amount     NUMBER,
Amount_CNY  DECIMAl(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CASE WHEN Currency ='EUR' THEN (Amount/0.14 ) 
                                                    WHEN Currency ='USD' THEN (Amount/0.13 ) 
                                                    WHEN Currency ='GBP' THEN (Amount/0.12 ) 
                                               END ) VIRTUAL);
```

[Generated Columns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

VIRTUAL: Column values are not stored, but are evaluated when rows are read, immediately after any BEFORE triggers. A virtual column takes no storage.

The default is VIRTUAL if neither keyword is specified.

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7UofiYE_)

Some data example for the above table.

```
INSERT INTO ABC_TABLE (Currency,Amount)
  SELECT 'EUR',100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'USD',300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GBP',200 FROM DUAL;
```

Select

```
SELECT * 
FROM ABC_TABLE;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> CURRENCY  AMOUNT  AMOUNT_CNY
>    EUR         100    714.29
>    USD         300    2307.69
>    GBP         200    1666.67
> ```